# Attempting to dissect a tutorial, but getting awkward behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am extremely new to `Angular.js` and am trying very hard to learn it, I need to adapt some of my projects to fit it, per some new requirements we've been handed.

One of my major problems was that I needed to reproduce certain behaviors over many pages, a typical `base model -> inheritance` issue. This was previously accomplished in `Typescript` by using natural classes and extending them.

In researching Angular, I learned that it doesn't really work this way out of the box. So I've sampled many different tutorials, and came across **[this one in particular](http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2014/02/14/angularjs-services-inheritance/)** which was very insightful, and quite interesting.

I have attempted to reproduce it on my own, using some slightly different layout and syntax for the sake of trying to understand it. But I cannot seem to get the behavior to match... the biggest change I made is that I'm not 'chaining' everything together, I instead go the route I learned when I first picked up angular, and declare a variable to add all of the controllers, and factories to, like this;

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('...', function($scope, ... );
app.factory('...', function($http, ...);
```

I have gone over my code several times, and checked it, double checked it, triple checked it, but when I run it, it doesn't function. If I copy/paste the exact code in the final **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revolunet/YLs26/light/)**, it works fine, so I am 100% certain I am making the mistake somewhere.

I am posting my own code here, in hopes that someone can tell me what I am doing wrong - because I am genuinely quite lost now. I am also including a forked **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/RG9X5/)** of my own code for easy running and comparison.

I wish I could list the exact error I am getting, but I'm simply not certain. It is a lot of strange output that actually goes back to the `angular.js` file, not my own, so I don't know where the error in my own code is.

## app.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    app.factory('SimpleGithubUser', function($http) {
        var apiUrl = 'https://api.github.com/';

        // instantiate our initial object
        var SimpleGithubUser = function( username ) {
            this.username = username;
            this.profile = null;
        };

        // define the getProfile method which will fetch data
        // from GH API and *returns* a promise
        SimpleGithubUser.prototype.getProfile = function(){
            // generally, javascript callbacks, like here the $http.get callback,
            // change the value of the 'this' variable inside it
            // so we need to keep a reference to the current instance of 'this'
            var self = this;

            return $http.get(apiUrl + 'users/' + this.username).then(function(response){
                // when we get the results, we store the data in user.profile
                self.profile = response.data;

                // promises success should always return something in order to allow chaining
                return response;
            });
        };

        return SimpleGithubUser;

    });

    app.factory('AdvancedGithubUser', function($http, SimpleGithubUser){
        var apiUrl = 'https://api.github.com/';

        // create our new custom object that reuse the original object constructor
        var AdvancedGithubUser = function(){
            SimpleGithubUser.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        // reuse the original object prototype
        AdvancedGithubUser.prototype = new SimpleGithubUser();

        // define a new internal private method for this object
        function getUserEvents() {
            var self = this;

            return $http.get(apiUrl + 'users/' + this.username + '/events').then(function(response){
                // attach the events API result to our user profile
                self.profile.events = response.data;
                // promises should always return a result
                return response;
            });
        }

        // now let's override our original getProfile method
        AdvancedGithubUser.prototype.getProfile = function(){
            var self = this;

            // we first call the original getProfile method (aka super method)
            var originalGetProfile = SimpleGithubUser.prototype.getProfile.apply(this, arguments);

            // we use promises chaining to add additional data
            return originalGetProfile.then(function(){
                // beforer returning the results,
                // call our new private method and bind 'this' to 'self'
                // we need to do this because the method is not part of the prototype
                return getUserEvents(self);
            });
        };

        return AdvancedGithubUser;
    });

    app.service('MyUserProfile', function(AdvancedGithubUser){
        var user = new AdvancedGithubUser('revolunet');
        user.getProfile();
        return user;
    });

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function(MyUserProfile){
        $scope.user = MyUserProfile;
        alert(MyUserProfile.location);
    });

    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, SimpleGithubUser, AdvancedGithubUser){
        $scope.users = [];

        $scope.fetchUsers = function(){
            $scope.users = [];
            var users = ['mhevery', 'igorminar', 'btford', 'substack', 'sindresorhus', 'n1k0', 'revolunet'];

            users.forEach(function(userName){
                var user = new AdvancedGithubUser(userName);
                user.getProfile().then(function(){
                    $scope.users.push(user);
                });
            })
        }
    })
})();
```

## HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <h1>{{ welcome }}</h1>

    <button ng-click="fetchUsers()">fetch some badass GitHub users data</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="{odd: $odd}" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <img class="gravatar" ng-src="{{ user.profile.avatar_url }}" /> <b>{{ user.profile.login }}</b> ({{ user.profile.location }})
            <div class="event">{{ user.profile.events[0].type }} : {{ user.profile.events[0].repo.name }}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You say "*If I copy/paste **the exact code** in the final jsFiddle, it works fine...*".  Then what is the difference? Are you not including the correct libraries?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out. The only difference that I am aware of is that I didn't declare everything by chaining them, but instead I declared them on that `app` variable.

Comment: Do you by any chance perform any minification on your code and not in the Fiddle?  I noticed that the syntax you use will not survive minification.

Comment: If you are using Chrome for debugging, download and install [`Batarang`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Batarang plugin told me nothing. It gives me the error ...`TypeError: Cannot set property 'events' of undefined` on line 67, which reads `self.profile.events = response.data;` - however this makes no sense to me. This is coded the __exact__ same way as in the tutorial, and that code works.

Comment: "It" being the normal debug console in Chrome and FireFox both.

Comment: man, I just don't get it. I've gone over it dozens of times. The code is completely identical. Even if I change to chaining like he does in the tutorial, it fails. It just makes zero sense to me.

Comment: AHA!!!!!!!! I FOUND IT!!!!!!!!! It's that very damn last line of `AdvancedGithubUser.prototype.getProfile` function override. I put down ... `return getUserEvents(self);`, the original code has `return getUserEvents.call(self);`.

Comment: FYI: Batarang creates a separate Angular tab. In this tab you need to enable it, only then you can debug Angular-specific stuff.

Comment: I will have to learn to use it. Do you know of any places that have some tutorials or examples on using it? The actual plugin information itself didn't tell me much.

Comment: I did not need anything. Once enabled it's very intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its Julien from the revolunet blog here :)

Well, in your code, you're simply calling `return getUserEvents(self);` when in my example i use `return getUserEvents.call(self);`. The difference is what will the `this` be in the `getUserEvents` function.

In your case it will be `window`, which doesnt have any `profile.events`, which cause your error, whereas in my case i force it to be the current `AdvancedGithubUser` instance thanks to the `call` function that change the `this` value in the function call.

The `this` behaviour in javascript can be quite confusing; it not depends on where it is located but instead from which context you use it.

Here's a good article on this subject : http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: Yes, that was it. It took me forever to track down. Such a tiny, tiny little thing making such an enormous difference.

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much for responding, by the way. It really means a lot to me. Your tutorial was amazing!